# loading screen on windows phone phonegap

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am making an app with phonegap that contains hundreds of mp3 sounds. 24mb all in all. My problem is that the splash screen dissapears after one second, and the app is then blank for about thirty seconds. The output panel on the debugger shows that it's going through all the mp3 files.

> INFO: Writing data for /app/www\sounds\sound01.mp3 and length = 21125
>   INFO: Writing data for /app/www\sounds\sound02.mp3 and length = 21125
>   etc.

If is understand correctly, everything in the www folder is being put into isolated storage.

1. Is there a way to keep the spash/loading screen until this process is finished?
2. Could I skip this process alltogether and just load sounds when they are needed?